# Error running wsgi in python27 and python36

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I downloaded mod_fcgid-2.3.9 and used it under Apache 2.4.
I did a 'pip install flup' in python 2.7, and try to run the following code to test wsgi.

```
from cgi import escape
import sys, os
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer

def app(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])

    yield '<h1>FastCGI Environment</h1>'

    yield '<table>'
    for k, v in sorted(environ.items()):
        yield '<tr><th>%s</th><td>%s</td></tr>' % (escape(k), escape(v))
    yield '</table>'

WSGIServer(app).run()
```

however, the following error encountered

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jl\Documents\00-wsgi.py", line 18, in <module> WSGIServer(app).run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flup\server\fcgi.py", line 112, in run
    sock = self._setupSocket()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flup\server\fcgi_base.py", line 978, in _setupSocket
    sock = socket.fromfd(FCGI_LISTENSOCK_FILENO, socket.AF_INET,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fromfd'
```

I tried to run the above under python36.
I did a 'pip install flup6' under python36 environment, then the above program is run and the following error encountered.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jl/Documents/00-wsgi36.py", line 20, in <module>
    WSGIServer(app).run()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\flup\server\fcgi.py", line 112, in run
    sock = self._setupSocket()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\flup\server\fcgi_base.py", line 988, in _setupSocket
    socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 460, in fromfd
    nfd = dup(fd)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

What should I do to solve the problems in both python27 and python36 environment?